# facebook ad metric vs google analytics metrics

Tags: google-analytics, facebook

My facebook ad metrics shows me a number of clicks in my ad. Also my google analytics is tracking the facebook ad source, but the number of clicks in my ad is almost 30% bigger than the number of visits that is being tracked by the google analytics from the facebook campaign source.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics doesn't track users that are logged into a Google account (Gmail, Adwords, Analytics etc) so the number you see from GA will almost always be lower than from the referring source itself.

If you're simply looking at the number of clicks from your ad I'd use the Facebook metrics however if you'd like to drill down further on those visitors I'd go with GA!

Comment: I don't think I understand... "GA doesn't track [any] users that are logged into a G account"?! Many of us these days are _permanently_ logged into our G accounts; are you saying that none of us are tracked by GA?!

Comment: Yes, makes no sense to me. Gmail now has more than 425 million users. So x/100 425 000 000 not being tracked by ga? Makes no sense.

Comment: It would be interesting to see a source on GA not tracking logged users

Comment: I was being thick, turns out Google only doesn't track the *keywords* of a logged in user, not the visit itself!

The difference in visits could be that the visitors are bouncing before your GA script has time to load, other than that I can't offer much more help!